How to authenticate app which get data from api server?
I am building an Android app, and server, that does not require users to log in. The app gets data from the server.
How can I authenticate requests to the server, that my app is requesting data from the server, not any malicious trying to take down the server?
How can I authenticate each request?

You can't.  Anything you used to authenticate code could be faked by malicious code, or a hacked version of your app.  What you can do is authenticate the user via shared secret (a password) that they need to enter in order to login, and use that to authenticate additional requests.  But you can't know for sure that it's your code originating the request, and you can't stop a user from using alternative code to access your server if they have the correct shared secret to access it.

You can't do anything in this case, you need to change it . User must login into your app , after that you can create one file(SharedPref) which stores the information and data regarding user and the settings or features user changed in your app. This way user will not have to login again and again until user chooses to logout , create an interface class in which you must create a request call for each setting in your database with the appropriate parameters in each request. I think this should few of your problems.

May be you can use following method:

Setup an api key on server and pass that on app side when make any api
request. Also pass package name, bundle Id or app version in every
request.

App version and package name you can use on server for request approval purpose
Just follow they way of google apis for Maps and Search places.
